# clojure assignment of variables in a loop function that returns a vector

Tags: clojure

My question is ... what would be a good way to update the values of   currentRow  nextRow bitPosition 
every time  (recur [currentRow nextRow bitPosition])) executes. Right now i am struggling with the fact that I can't just do something easy like this in clojure. Instead i am trapped in this world of pain where I cant even figure out how to set a variable to a new value in a loop.

//I wish i could just do this

```
currentRow =(get myVector  0)
```

//here my code

```
 (loop [myVector []]
        (let [
            rule ruleParam
            currentRow currentRowParam
            nextRow 2r0
            bitPosition 2r0
           ]

    (when (bit-test rule (bit-and currentRow 2r111)) 
       (
           (bit-shift-right currentRow 1)
           (bit-set nextRow 1)
           (inc bitPosition)
      ))
    (when (= false  (bit-test rule (bit-and currentRow 2r111)) )
        (bit-shift-right currentRow 1)
         (bit-set nextRow 1)
         (inc bitPosition)
      )
    (recur [currentRow nextRow bitPosition]))

     ))
```

## Solution to my question. Thanks for all your guidance.

```
(defn firstFunc [[rule currentRowParam]]
  (let  [currentRowLocal (bit-shift-left currentRowParam 1) nextRowLocal 2r0 bitPositionLocal 0]

  (loop [currentRow currentRowLocal nextRow nextRowLocal bitPosition bitPositionLocal]

  (if (< bitPosition 31)
  (if (bit-test rule (bit-and currentRow 2r111))
   (recur 
      (bit-shift-right currentRow 1) 
      (bit-set nextRow bitPosition)
      (inc bitPosition) 
    );end recur
  (recur 
      (bit-shift-right currentRow 1) 
      nextRow
      (inc bitPosition) 
    );end recur
  )
  ;else
   nextRow);end if  (< bitPosition 31)
  );end loop
  );end let
);end defn firstFunc


(firstFunc2 [2r1110 2r11])
```

Comment: where are ruleParam and currentRowParam coming from? It's silly to bind to them inside a let within the loop, they cannot be changed while the loop is running

Comment: never mind, I figured it out from your final recur call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is that you can't.

- Local 'variables' are variable only in a mathematical sense: you can consider 
  what is evinced when they take various values, but you can't *assign* a value to them.
- Functions do not change locals.

For example, you have

```
   (bit-shift-right currentRow 1)
   (bit-set nextRow 1)
   (inc bitPosition)
```

These expressions do nothing. Let's take the first one

```
       (bit-shift-right currentRow 1)
```

This *returns* the value of `currentRow` bit-shifted right by 1. It does not change `currentRow`. Since you have done nothing with the returned value, it is forgotten.

To use the value returned by a function, you can `recur` to a `loop`, which is just a `let` you can `recur` to.

If we recast your code accordingly, we get something like

```
(loop [myVector []]
  (loop [rule ruleParam
         currentRow currentRowParam
         nextRow 2r0
         bitPosition 2r0]
    (if (bit-test rule (bit-and currentRow 2r111))
      (recur
       rule
       (bit-shift-right currentRow 1)
       (bit-set nextRow 1)
       (inc bitPosition))
      (recur
       rule
       (bit-shift-right currentRow 1)
       (bit-set nextRow 1)
       (inc bitPosition)))
    (recur rule currentRow nextRow bitPosition)))
```

... where the complementary `if` conditions have been elided.

This is still nonsense.

- All the final expressions in the `loop` are `recur`s - so you never
  escape it.
- The final `recur` is never reached, as one of the two above it
  is always enacted.

---

You might find the easier problems at [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) help you to get to grips with the language.